# Ember Pass property created inside parent component to child components

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In my Ember app, I have a property that I create inside the `init()` method of a parent component. I want to pass this into children.

```
// app/component/parent.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ParentProperty from 'somewhere';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        let model = this.get('model');
        let moreData = this.get('moreData');
        this.parentProperty = new ParentProperty(model, moreData);
    }

    click(e) {
        this.get('moreData').doSomthing();
    }
});

// app/component/application.hbs
{{#parent model=model moreData=moreData}}
    // Here, I want to pass the `parentProperty` created 
    // in the init of the parent component.
    {{child parentProperty=parent.parentProperty}}
{{/parent}}
```

I know I can use the `{{with}}` helper to create a ParentProperty, wrap the parent and child, and pass it down to both of them, but that's not what I want to do. Is this possible?

Comment: This template is your routes template, not your parents component template, right? And you can't access a property of a component from outside. However you could pass it to the `yield` helper to expose it.

Comment: Right, that's the route template. I've edited the question. How would I expose it from the yield helper?

Answer (score 1):

As @Lux suggested, I could achieve this using the yield helper.

```
// app/component/parent.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ParentProperty from 'somewhere';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        let model = this.get('model');
        let moreData = this.get('moreData');
        this.parentProperty = new ParentProperty(model, moreData);
    }

    click(e) {
        this.get('moreData').doSomthing();
    }
});

// app/component/parent.hbs
{{yield parentProperty}}

// app/component/application.hbs
{{#parent model=model moreData=moreData as |parentProperty|}}
    {{child parentProperty=parentProperty}}
{{/parent}}
```